# Adding an URL image as a legend through PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, legend

I am trying to add an URL image as a legend to a layer in QGIS programmatically using Python.I can do it manually through the layer menu (see image below). However, I have not been able to find any examples of how to do this using Python.

[image]

Comment: i dont understand why my question got closed and is considered off-topic...
Could an administrator explain please ?

Comment: For questions about code please always include a code attempt.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like:

```py
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('LIMITES_ADMINISTRATIVES_EXPRESS.LATEST')[0]
legend = QgsDefaultRasterLayerLegend(lyr)
url = 'https://link/to/image/source.jpg'
lyr.setLegendPlaceholderImage(url)
lyr.setLegend(legend)
legend.itemsChanged.emit()
```